# Nginx: Multiple PHP fpm on subdirectories in one domain

Tags: php, nginx

I need to have multiple PHP-FPMs on single domain.

Example:
services.local/notification -> notification:9000
services.local/auth         -> auth:9000

So, I have a vhost configuration:

```
server {
    server_name services.local;
    root /www;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/services/*.conf;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
}
```

And I have a notification.conf

```
location /notification {
    root /www/;
    index app.php index.html;

    #try_files $uri $uri /notification/web/app.php?$is_args$args;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /notification/web/app.php last;
}


location /notification/web/app.php {
    fastcgi_pass notification-upstream;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/notification/web/app.php;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
}
```

The problem is that every rewrite to the app.php results in downloading it's contents, not passing it to FPM.

When I access the app.php directly then it's passed to PHP-FPM, only problem is with a combination of subdirectory + PHP-FPM + rewrite

I think I tried everything for two days and I don't have any other ideas.
This config was rebuilded 50 times :)

Comment: Hi, can you please give advice to my question : https://serverfault.com/questions/865588/nginx-multiple-php-endpoint?noredirect=1#comment1112712_865588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I don't know only if it would work with static assets, probably not, but this was not my case. Feel free to beautify and simplify this code as I'm aware that it looks a little bit ugly but it's working perfectly.

```
location ~ /notification {
    set $new_request_uri /;
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/notification(.+)$) {
        set $new_request_uri $1;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~ ^/notification\?(.+)$) {
        set $new_request_uri /?$1;
    }

    set $new_document_uri /;
    if ($document_uri ~ ^/notification(.+)$) {
        set $new_document_uri $1;
    }

    fastcgi_pass wolnosciowiec_notification:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI     $new_request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI    $new_document_uri;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     /www/notification/web/app.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/notification/web/app.php;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT   /www/notification/web;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
}
```